# Pagination on two Active record objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, limit, offset

```
taxon = Spree::Taxon.find_by_permalink('categories/outlet')    
on_sale_products = taxon.products.on_hand
discontinued_variant_products = load_products_with_discontinued_variants
@PageItemLimit = 4
 if params[:page]
  offset = (params[:page].to_i) *  @PageItemLimit
else
  offset = 0
end
products = discontinued_variant_products | on_sale_products
products = products[(offset) , @PageItemLimit]
```

---

```
def load_products_with_discontinued_variants
 key = Spree::Product.discontinued_variants_cache_key
  product_ids = Rails.cache.fetch key, expires_at: 1.day do
   Spree::Product
    .with_discontinued_variants
    .select { |product| product.variants.any? { |v| v.on_sale? && 
     v.in_stock? } }
    .pluck(:id)
    end
 Spree::Product.with_discontinued_variants.where("id IN (?)", product_ids)
end
```

---

```
add_search_scope :with_discontinued_variants do
 select(' distinct spree_products.*').includes(variants: { prices: { 
  sale_prices: :calculator }}).where(discontinued_variants: true)
end
```

This is my current set-up for pagination,

discontinued_variant_products is of type active record relation object.
on_sale_products is of type active record associations.

currently the offset, limit logic is applied to products which are an array, holding the result of active record object unions (All of the data).
I want to use the limit and offset keyword on the active record object for pagination but as they are two objects, handling limit-offset on both 
separately is giving incorrect results, can some provide me with correct logic for it or if the two active record objects can be merged into a new Active record object,
limit-offset can be applied to it easily.

Comment: not clear to me how the first snippet relates to the other two.

Comment: they the function definition, for functions used in first snippet